# Android native crash with signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE)

Tags: android, crash

I'm getting a lot of native crashes from one of my android apps in production. This crash has increased since the update of AdMob version 19.4.0 to 20.6.0, which has rarely happened before. I also use Facebook and Unity ad mediation. All these crashes are coming from Android 10.0.

**Stacktrace 1:**

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.example.app <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000005fcb2  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+166)
  #00  pc 0000000000005abf  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+174)
  #00  pc 000000000031bc5f  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaOpenGLPipeline::swapBuffers(android::uirenderer::renderthread::Frame const&, bool, SkRect const&, android::uirenderer::FrameInfo*, bool*)+94)
  #00  pc 0000000000324a61  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::draw()+672)
  #00  pc 0000000000323ed7  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread13DrawFrameTask11postAndWaitEvE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS6_EEFvvEEclEv$c303f2d2360db58ed70a2d0ac7ed911b+174)
  #00  pc 000000000032f5ef  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+158)
  #00  pc 000000000032f447  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+54)
  #00  pc 000000000000d8bb  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+186)
  #00  pc 00000000000a8147  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+20)
  #00  pc 0000000000061467  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
```

Another similar crash `signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL)` but with a different stack trace spiked recently. This crash is occurring only on android 9.0.

**Stacktrace 2:**

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.example.app <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000001ccc6  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+58)
  #00  pc 0000000000006ccd  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+156)
  #00  pc 0000000000466955  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::debug::GlesErrorCheckWrapper::assertNoErrors(char const*)+88)
  #00  pc 0000000000140e87  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::GLFunctorDrawable::onDraw(SkCanvas*)+2102)
  #00  pc 000000000044c991  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+212)
  #00  pc 000000000044d3a5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+156)
  #00  pc 00000000004349fd  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+272)
  #00  pc 0000000000434d13  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+202)
  #00  pc 000000000044c921  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+100)
  #00  pc 000000000044d3a5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+156)
  #00  pc 00000000004349fd  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+272)
  #00  pc 0000000000434d13  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+202)
  #00  pc 000000000044c921  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+100)
  #00  pc 000000000044d3a5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+156)
  #00  pc 00000000004349fd  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+272)
  #00  pc 0000000000434d13  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+202)
  #00  pc 000000000044c921  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+100)
  #00  pc 000000000044d3a5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+156)
  #00  pc 00000000004349fd  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+272)
  #00  pc 0000000000434d13  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+202)
  #00  pc 000000000044c921  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+100)
  #00  pc 000000000044d3a5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+156)
  #00  pc 00000000004349fd  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+272)
  #00  pc 0000000000434d13  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+202)
  #00  pc 000000000044c921  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+100)
  #00  pc 000000000044d3a5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+156)
  #00  pc 00000000004349fd  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+272)
  #00  pc 0000000000434d13  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+202)
  #00  pc 000000000044c921  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+100)
  #00  pc 000000000044d3a5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+156)
  #00  pc 00000000004349fd  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+272)
  #00  pc 0000000000434d13  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+202)
  #00  pc 000000000044c921  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+100)
  #00  pc 000000000044d3a5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+156)
  #00  pc 00000000004349fd  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+272)
  #00  pc 0000000000434d13  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+202)
  #00  pc 000000000044c921  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+100)
  #00  pc 000000000044d3a5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+156)
  #00  pc 00000000004349fd  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+272)
  #00  pc 0000000000434d13  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+202)
  #00  pc 000000000044c921  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+100)
  #00  pc 000000000044d3a5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+156)
  #00  pc 00000000004349fd  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+272)
  #00  pc 0000000000434d13  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+202)
  #00  pc 000000000044c921  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+100)
  #00  pc 000000000044d3a5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+156)
  #00  pc 00000000004349fd  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+272)
  #00  pc 0000000000434d13  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+202)
  #00  pc 000000000044c921  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+100)
  #00  pc 000000000044d3a5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+156)
  #00  pc 00000000004349fd  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+272)
  #00  pc 0000000000434d13  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+202)
  #00  pc 000000000044c921  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+100)
  #00  pc 000000000044d3a5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+156)
  #00  pc 00000000004349fd  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+272)
  #00  pc 0000000000434d13  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+202)
  #00  pc 000000000044c921  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+100)
  #00  pc 000000000044d3a5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkLiteDL::draw(SkCanvas*) const+156)
  #00  pc 00000000004349fd  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::drawContent(SkCanvas*) const+272)
  #00  pc 0000000000434d13  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::RenderNodeDrawable::forceDraw(SkCanvas*)+202)
  #00  pc 000000000044c921  /system/lib/libhwui.so (SkDrawable::draw(SkCanvas*, SkMatrix const*)+100)
  #00  pc 00000000001491c3  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaPipeline::renderFrameImpl(android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue const&, SkRect const&, std::__1::vector<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>, std::__1::allocator<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>>> const&, bool, bool, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, SkCanvas*)+402)
  #00  pc 00000000004696f7  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaPipeline::renderFrame(android::uirenderer::LayerUpdateQueue const&, SkRect const&, std::__1::vector<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>, std::__1::allocator<android::sp<android::uirenderer::RenderNode>>> const&, bool, bool, android::uirenderer::Rect const&, sk_sp<SkSurface>)+70)
  #00  pc 0000000000146935  /system/lib/libhwui.so
  #00  pc 000000000046c3c5  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread13DrawFrameTask11postAndWaitEvE3$_0NS_9allocatorIS6_EEFvvEEclEv$c303f2d2360db58ed70a2d0ac7ed911b+576)
  #00  pc 0000000000433d4f  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+122)
  #00  pc 000000000015abd3  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+178)
  #00  pc 000000000000c08b  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+166)
  #00  pc 0000000000063495  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+22)
  #00  pc 000000000001de89  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+24)
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't reproduce the crash on any of my phones. Any hints to resolve this crash will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have encountered same issues like you on Android 10.0. Did you manage to find any solution?